# Record audio from MediaPlayer and Microphone while recording video from a Surface

Tags: android

How would I go about pulling audio from a MediaPlayer and piping it into a MediaRecorder? I believe I'll actually have to use a MediaMuxer in the end. The end goal is to capture video from a Surface and mix the audio from a playing video and the device's microphone. I'm already recording video from the Surface and audio from the microphone. I just need to find out a way to pull audio from a video that's playing and mix it into the recording.

Thanks!